# Can we omit const on local variables in constexpr functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, c++14, constexpr

For example:

```
constexpr int g() { return 30; }    

constexpr int f()
{
    // Can we omit const?
    const int x = g();
    const int y = 10;

    return x + y;
}
```

Is there **any point to ever** declare local variables in a `constexpr` function with `const`?

Aren't `constexpr` functions with `const` local variables **equivalent** to those with no `const`?

In other words, does `constexpr` on a function **impose** (imply) `const` on its local variables?

Comment: I disagree with your premise that omitting `const` makes a function look "cleaner". Also, no, I don't think so. But I'm no `constexpr`t.

Comment: You can even [change them](http://ideone.com/L4Oa68)! (And its logical, it does not make function _not pure_)

Comment: @LeoHeinsaar I think you mean less non-whitespace characters, because otherwise it can be trivially made 'cleaner' by that definition in a way that will almost universally be interpreted as unreadable.

Comment: @LeoHeinsaar so you think obfuscated C++ is cleaner because it has fewer characters?

Comment: Here is the cleanest: `constexpr int f(){int x=g(),y=10;return x+y;}` (seriously)

Comment: "In other words, does `constexpr` on a function **impose** (imply) `const` on its local variables?" No. As would have been clear from writing some simple code to test that question. Modifiable variables in `constexpr` functions are an extremely important part of their usefulness.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The same arguments for declaring variables as `const` in non-`constexpr` functions also apply to `constexpr` functions:

- Declaring a variable `const` documents the fact that it won't ever be changed. This may in some instances help make the function more readable.
- Declaring a variable `const` affects overload resolution, and may make `h(x)` resolve `h` differently depending on whether `x` is `const`.

Of course, in the opposite direction, as mentioned in comments already:

Even in `constexpr` functions, local variables may be changed. If those variables are then changed so that they are `const`, attempts to change them will no longer be accepted.

Comment: I think this is a good answer. Without harder thought it may make an impression that `constexpr` on a function somehow imposes (implies) constness on everything inside it, including local variables (because, for example, you can't call a non-constexpr functions from it). Thanks.

Comment: Of course, const local variables cannot be moved from on return. I'm very wary of const for locals for this reason.

Answer (score 17):

In **this** particular example the local variables would be best declared `constexpr`, not `const`, because they **can** be computed at compile time:

```
constexpr int g() { return 30; }    

constexpr int f()
{
    constexpr int x = g();
    constexpr int y = 10;

    return x + y;
}
```

When `f()` is called at run time, without the `constexpr` on `x` and `y`, (with or without the `const` on `x` and `y`) you are giving the compiler the option to initialize `x` and `y` at run time instead of compile time.  With the `constexpr` on `x` and `y`, the compiler *shall* compute `x` and `y` at compile time, even when `f()` is executed at run time.

In a different function however, `constexpr` can't always be used.  For example if `f()` and `g()` took a parameter:

```
constexpr int g(int z) { return z+30; }    

constexpr int f(int z)
{
    const int x = g(z);
    constexpr int y = 10;

    return x + y;
}
```

Now `x` can not be marked `constexpr` because `z` may not be a compile-time constant, and there is currently no way to mark it as such.  So in this case, marking `x` `const` is the best you can do.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to require to imply `constexpr` on local variables that aren't changed?

Comment: @LeoHeinsaar: I'm afraid not.  In this example, what if `g()` is not marked `constexpr`?  In that case it's result `x` can not be marked `constexpr`, and the compiler is within its rights to compute `g()` at run time.  Perhaps `g()` needs to make a phone call to get its result...

Comment: Oh I see. That is revealing. Thanks Howard.

Answer (score 4):

You not only  *can*, but sometimes you *must* (*i.e.* if the variable changes), *eg*:

```
constexpr size_t f(size_t n) {
    size_t val = 1;
    if (n == 0) val++;
    return val;
}
char arr0[f(0)] = {'a', 'x'};
char arr1[f(1)] = {'y'};
```

is fine in C++14.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a function can't be evaluated at compile time and therefore can't be called in a constant expression. Specifying a function as constexpr indicates that it can be used in constant expressions IF its input arguments are constants. For example this...

```
constexpr int n = func(7);
```

... must be evaluated at compile time.

That's the meaning of constexpr before functions. This being the case, it doesn't follow that the local variables inside the function don't have to be specified const.